# ClassCastException in getApplication method

Tags: android, casting, classcastexception, runtimeexception

I'm getting the classcastexception in the getapplication() method. I've searched a lot of forums and similar questions but couldn't find a solution.
(I've included the application in the manifest)
It'll be a great a help if anyone could resolve this problem.

Here's my code:

```
//This is the source of error (I think)
blApplication = (BlueListApplication)getApplication();

itemList = blApplication.getItemList();
```

note: blApplication is the object of class BlueListApplication

stack trace:

```
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application     com.example.blue_list_android_base.MainActivity: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.blue_list_android_base.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4263)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:143)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1301)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.blue_list_android_base.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application
03-22 00:23:23.472: E/AndroidRuntime(27669):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:997)
```

let me know if any more information is needed.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here's my manifest file:
please check if I've included the applications correctly.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.blue_list_android_base"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <!-- Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />



<application
    android:name="com.example.blue_list_android_base.MainActivity"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.blue_list_android_base.EditActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit" >
    </activity>
</application>

<application android:icon="@drawable/logo" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:name="com.example.blue_list_android_base.BlueListApplication"/>

</manifest>
```

EDIT 2:

new stack trace:

```
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.blue_list_android_base: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.blue_list_android_base
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4263)
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:143)
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1301)
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 01:16:08.552: E/AndroidRuntime(8053):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two `<application>` elements in your manifest. Remove the second one and replace the value of the `android:name` attribute in the first one with the fully qualified name of your Application class `com.example.blue_list_android_base.BlueListApplication`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blue_list_android_base"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    ...

    <application
        android:name="com.example.blue_list_android_base.BlueListApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    ...

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It still doesn't solves the problem. It shows a new error now.

Comment: Then you have more then one problem :) What's the new error?

Comment: Does the `android:name` attribute by any chance read `com.example.blue_list_android_base` instead of `com.example.blue_list_android_base.BlueListApplication`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.blue_list_android_base.MainActivity"
...
</application>
```

`MainActivity` is not a subclass of `Application`. Elsewhere in the manifest, you claim that `MainActivity` is a subclass of `Activity`. Java does not support multiple inheritance, so only one of those two can be true (at most).

In the `android:name` attribute of `<application>` -- if you need one at all -- you need to have the name of a class that extends `Application`.

Comment: is it necessary for the activities to be children of application?

Comment: @Ish: If you mean from an XML standpoint, yes. As cketti noticed (and I did not), you have two `<application>` elements, which itself is not correct. There should only be one, and your `<activity>` elements will be children of that `<application>`.